# I need to make a binary table with two classes

Tags: java, bluej

I need to call a method from my binary class to make it into a table, the class is called `ShepNumber` and method called `toBinaryString`and I know it works i just need to find a way to put it in this code for the table.

```
`public class Multiplicationtable
{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tableSize = 4 ;
        printMultiplicationTable(tableSize);
    }

    public static void printMultiplicationTable(int tableSize) {
        // first print the top header row
        System.out.format("      ");
        for(int i = 1; i<=tableSize;i++ ) {
            System.out.format("%4d",i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");

        for(int i = 1 ;i<=tableSize;i++) {
            // print left most column first
            System.out.format("%4d |",i);
            for(int j=1;j<=tableSize;j++) {
                I need something here that will call the class and make the binary in the table. 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}`
```

This is the other code for the binary conversion.

```
    public class ShepNumber
{
    // declare varibles
    String binary="";
    int testingnumber ;
    public ShepNumber(int number)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        testingnumber = number;
    }

   // the conversion of the number 
    public String toBinaryString()
    {
        int modtest;
        modtest= testingnumber%2; 
        binary=modtest+binary;
        this.testingnumber=testingnumber/2;
        if (testingnumber>0){
            toBinaryString();

        }
        return binary;
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you explain what a binary table is?  Do mean  square multiplication table (which might use a "2D" array or some similar data structure?

Comment: @WJS it is really just a multiplication table but instead of like 16 it would be the binary number of 16